# Load encrypted PKCS1 private key from file

Tags: go, rsa, private-key, pkcs#11

I have a PKCS1 private key in a file and I load it using

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Then, I try to convert it into private key object

```
block, _ := pem.Decode(b)
der, err := x509.DecryptPEMBlock(block, []byte("qwerty"))
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

bytes := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "RSA PRIVATE KEY", Bytes: der})

return x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(bytes)
```

But this code throws exception in `DecryptPEMBlock`

```
x509: no DEK-Info header in block
```

I didn't find any documentation about this in golang

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No DEK-Info header in block" when attempting to read encrypted private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981821/no-dek-info-header-in-block-when-attempting-to-read-encrypted-private-key)

Answer (score 3):

I made a mistake with my private key file and here is a working code

```
func GetPrivateKey(path string) (*rsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode(b)
    der, err := x509.DecryptPEMBlock(block, []byte(*PrivateKeyPassword))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(der)
}
```

P.S. Go does have a package to decrypt PKCS1 private keys, but does not have for PKCS8.

Answer (score 0):

Go does not have package to decode PKCS files it seems

Checkout this link for more details [PKCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981821/no-dek-info-header-in-block-when-attempting-to-read-encrypted-private-key)

I cant find a package to decode PKCS1 keys

Use this package to decode the [PKCS8](https://github.com/youmark/pkcs8/blob/master/pkcs8.go#L103) files, there are some packages to decode PKCS8, PKCS10, PKCS12 but not for PKCS1